# MongoDB compare within call string to int

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a MongDB collection in which my documents have a date stored as a string like this:

```
"data": {
    "type": "MatchData",
    "matchId": "5b34f2d527f0d904f8ee4bbf",
    "groupId": "5b2a032ffc37de04f30dc412",
    "leaderboardId": "5b2a0387fc37de04f30e149d",
    "matchTitle": "",
    "date": "20180628144304"
}
```

As you can see, the date is saved as a string, but I want to be able to find all records with a date older than the current:

```
var currDate = 20180928000000
dbCollection('matches').find( { "groupId": groupId, "$lt": {"date": currDate} } );
```

The current example is not working since the currDate is a integer and the date from document is a string!? How can I use parseInt inside the query or is there another way?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Dumb question, but does something like  `{"date": currDate.toString()}` works ?
Also if I had to store date in mongodb, well.. I would store them as date (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/) and not string, int or something that is not date

Comment: You can use `$toInt` function in newer version (4.0). Something like `dbCollection('matches').find({"groupId": groupId,"$expr":{"$lt":[{"$toInt": "$date" }, currDate]}});`

Comment: If you are using 4.0 then you can use `$toInt` aggregation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either convert your input parameter `currDate` to string

```
var currDate = "20180928000000"
dbCollection('matches').find({ "groupId": groupId, "$lt": { "date": currDate } })
```

or If you are using **4.0**

then you can use [**`$toInt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/) aggregation operator

```
dbCollection('matches').find({
  "groupId": groupId,
  "$expr": { "$lt": [{ "$toInt": "$date" }, currDate]}
})
```